# Unable to install platformio-ide-terminal in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, platformio

I am a beginner in python and just started learning it since yesterday and I am facing this below error:

```
Installing “platformio-ide-terminal@2.10.0” failed.

> node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt- 
multiarch
> prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js

C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=6.1.12 runtime=electron arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.52.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\indra\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.52.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\indra\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020914-12224-l2dhgv.ez4lo No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\***\.atom\.apm\_logs\2020-10-14T12_05_28_400Z-debug.log
```

**Atom Version**: 1.52.0

**platformio-ide-terminal Version**: 2.10.0

Please help me here.

Comment: FYI, I have tried restarting my machine and reinstalling atom in my machine. But it didn't work

Comment: Did you try installing the extension for ide-platformio-terminal. are you using VS Studio or Atom? you error message mentions VS Studio in a lot of plces... Maybe thats normal. Go to atom.io/packages and look for platformio-ide-terminal and load that into Atom. Then go to extensions in Atom and turn that package on.

Answer (score 4):

**Firstly**

Same issue happened to me today. Now after uninstalling it i can't install it back. In some github discussion, i've seen some were suggesting to uninstall atom and then reinstall previous version of atom.

Check out more here:
https://discuss.atom.io/t/cannot-install-platformio-ide-terminal-2-9-1-on-atom/67012/7

**Second Option:**
(Uninstall whatever package you are using for terminal [optional].)

Now,

1. Open Atom and Go to File -> Setting -> install
2. Search for `terminus` and click install
3. After installing terminus, find `Shell Override` and write `C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe` in it
4. Restart Atom
5. Find a plus (+) sign at the left-bottom of Atom window. Then click on it! Hurray! Terminal is opened!

I've followed the second option and now working in terminal on Atom!

Answer (score 0):

Close and uninstall the Atom editor and then, delete the 'atom' directory in 'C:\Users\current_user\AppData'.

Now re-install the Atom editor again and it should work.

(PS: "AppData" is a hidden directory)